# Regex to find the function declarations from text obtained from Apps Script API

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

When one makes a request from the App Script API to return all of the files and functions for a given project this is what a source file looks like:

```
"function traverse(o, func) {\n  for (var i in o) {\n    func.apply(this, [i, o[i]]);\n    if (o[i] !== null && typeof (o[i]) == \"object\") {\n      traverse(o[i], func);\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfunction daysInMonth(m = 0) {\n  return new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), m + 1, 0).getDate();\n}\n\nfunction getMyDataURI(fileId) {\n  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);\n  return file.getBlob().getDataAsString();\n}\n\nfunction dataFromGSheets() {\n  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();\n  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(\"Sheet1\");\n  const [header, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();\n  const choices = {};\n  header.forEach((title, index) =\u003e {\n    choices[title] = data.map(row =\u003e row[index]).filter(e =\u003e e)\n  });\n  return choices;\n}\n\nfunction boldMyWords() {\n  const red = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor('red').setBold(true).build();\n  const bold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();\n  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();\n  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();\n  const dsr = 3;\n  const rg = sh.getRange(3, 1, sh.getLastRow() - dsr + 1, sh.getLastColumn());\n  rg.clearFormat().setWrap(true);\n  let vs = rg.getDisplayValues();\n  let r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Enter words to search for separated by commas', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);\n  if (r.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {\n    let wordA = r.getResponseText().split(',');\n    vs.forEach((r, i) =\u003e {\n      r.forEach((c, j) =\u003e {\n        let idxObj = { pA: [] };\n        wordA.forEach(w =\u003e {\n          let re = new RegExp('(\\\\W|^)' + w.trim().toLowerCase() + '(\\\\W|$)', 'g');\n          let found = [...c.toLowerCase().matchAll(re)];\n          found.forEach(f =\u003e {\n            if (!idxObj.hasOwnProperty(w)) {\n              idxObj[w] = [];\n              idxObj[w].push((f.index \u003e 0) ? f.index + 1 : f.index);\n              idxObj.pA.push(w);\n            } else {\n              idxObj[w].push((f.index));\n            }\n          })\n        });\n        if (idxObj.pA.length \u003e 0) {\n          let cell = sh.getRange(i + dsr, j + 1);\n          let val = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(c);\n          idxObj.pA.forEach((p, k) =\u003e {\n            idxObj[p].forEach(idx =\u003e {\n              val.setTextStyle(idx, idx + p.length, red);\n              val.setTextStyle(idx, idx + p.length, bold);\n            });\n          });\n          cell.setRichTextValue(val.build());\n        }\n      });\n    });\n  }\n  ss.toast('EOF')\n}\n\nfunction boldMyName() {\n  const bold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();\n  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();\n  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();\n  const dsr = 3;\n  const rg = sh.getRange(3, 1, sh.getLastRow() - dsr + 1, sh.getLastColumn());\n  rg.clearFormat().setWrap(true);\n  let vs = rg.getDisplayValues();\n  vs.forEach((r, i) =\u003e {\n    r.forEach((c, j) =\u003e {\n      let idx = c.indexOf(':');\n      if (~idx) {\n        let cell = sh.getRange(i + dsr, j + 1);\n        let val = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(c);\n        val.setTextStyle(0, idx, bold);\n        cell.setRichTextValue(val.build());\n      }\n    });\n  });\n}\n\nfunction monthArray() {\n  const mA = [...Array.from(new Array(12).keys(), x =\u003e Utilities.formatDate(new Date(2021, x, 15), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), \"MMMM\"))];\n  Logger.log(mA.join(','));\n}\n\nvar level = 1;\nfunction getFnF(folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder()) {\n  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();\n  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0')\n  const files = folder.getFiles();\n  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, level).setValue(folder.getName()).setFontWeight('bold');\n  if (files.hasNext()) {\n    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, level).setValue('Files:');\n  }\n  while (files.hasNext()) {\n    let file = files.next();\n    let firg = sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, level + 1);\n    firg.setValue(Utilities.formatString(file.getName()));\n  }\n  const subfolders = folder.getFolders()\n  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {\n    let subfolder = subfolders.next();\n    level++;\n    getFnF(subfolder);\n  }\n  level--;\n}\n\nfunction getFilesAndFolders() {\n  const fldr = DriveApp.getRootFolder();\n  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet0').clearContents();\n  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Entry');\n  getFnF(fldr);\n  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('EOF');\n}\n\nfunction getFnF1(folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder()) {\n  let tree = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('FnF'));\n  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(tree));\n  if (tree.level \u003c level) {\n    tree.level = level;\n    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('FnF', JSON.stringify(tree));\n  }\n  const files = folder.getFiles();\n  let row = Array.from([...Array(level).keys()], ((x, i) =\u003e { if (i == level - 1) { x = folder.getName(); } else { x = ''; } return x; }));\n  tree.txt.push(row);\n  row = Array.from([...Array(level).keys()], ((x, i) =\u003e { if (i == level - 1) { x = 'bold'; } else { x = 'normal'; } return x; }));\n  tree.fwt.push(row);\n  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('FnF', JSON.stringify(tree));\n  if (files.hasNext()) {\n    let row = Array.from([...Array(level).keys()], ((x, i) =\u003e { if (i == level - 1) { x = 'Files:'; } else { x = ''; } return x; }));\n    tree.txt.push(row);\n    tree.fwt.push(['normal']);\n    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('FnF', JSON.stringify(tree));\n  }\n  while (files.hasNext()) {\n    let file = files.next();\n    let row = Array.from([...Array(level + 1).keys()], ((x, i) =\u003e { if (i == level) { x = file.getName(); } else { x = ''; } return x; }));\n    tree.txt.push(row);\n    tree.fwt.push(['normal']);\n    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('FnF', JSON.stringify(tree));\n  }\n  const subfolders = folder.getFolders()\n  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {\n    let subfolder = subfolders.next();\n    level++;\n    getFnF1(subfolder);\n  }\n  level--;\n}\n\nfunction getFilesAndFolders1() {\n  const fldr = null;\n  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();\n  ss.toast(\"Entry\");\n  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');\n  sh.clearContents();\n  SpreadsheetApp.flush();\n  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('FnF', JSON.stringify({ txt: [], fwt: [], level: 0 }));\n  getFnF1();\n  //Logger.log(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('FnF'));\n  let tree = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('FnF'));\n  const l = tree.level + 1\n  tree.txt.forEach(r =\u003e {\n    if (r.length \u003c l) {\n      //Array.from(Array(l - r.length).keys()).forEach(e =\u003e r.push(''));\n      r.splice(r.length, 0, ...Array(l - r.length).fill(''));\n    }\n  });\n  tree.fwt.forEach(r =\u003e {\n    if (r.length \u003c l) {\n      //Array.from(Array(l - r.length).keys()).forEach(e =\u003e r.push('normal'));\n      r.splice(r.length, 0, ...Array(l - r.length).fill('normal'));\n    }\n  });\n  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(tree));\n  sh.getRange(1, 1, tree.txt.length, tree.level + 1).setValues(tree.txt);\n  sh.getRange(1, 1, tree.fwt.length, tree.level + 1).setFontWeights(tree.fwt);\n  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty('FnF');\n  ss.toast(\"EOF\");\n}\n\nfunction calendarMonthlyForYear() {\n  var dA = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];\n  var oA = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];//you can change the first day of the week by shifting the array\n  //var oA=['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];\n  var dObj = {};\n  oA.forEach(function (e, i) { dObj[e] = i });\n  var mA = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];\n  var cA = [];\n  var bA = [];\n  var wA = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null];\n  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();\n  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(\"Cal\");\n  if (!sh) { var sh = ss.insertSheet('Cal'); }\n  sh.clear();\n  var year = new Date().getFullYear();\n  for (var i = 0; i \u003c 12; i++) {\n    var month = new Date(year, i, 1).getMonth();\n    var dates = new Date(year, i + 1, 0).getDate();\n    cA.push([mA[month], dates, '', '', '', '', '']);\n    bA.push(['#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff']);\n    cA.push(oA)\n    bA.push(['#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00']);\n    var d = [];\n    var ddd = [];\n    for (var j = 0; j \u003c dates; j++) {\n      var day = new Date(year, i, j + 1).getDay();\n      var date = new Date(year, i, j + 1).getDate();\n      if (day \u003c wA.length) {\n        wA[dObj[dA[day]]] = date;\n      }\n      //if(day==wA.length-1 || date==dates) {\n      if (dA[day] == oA[wA.length - 1] || date == dates) {\n        cA.push(wA);\n        bA.push(['#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff']);\n        wA = ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''];\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  sh.getRange(1, 1, cA.length, cA[0].length).setValues(cA);\n  //sh.getRange(1,1,cA.length,cA[0].length).setBackgrounds(bA);\n  sh.getRange(1, 1, cA.length, cA[0].length).setBackground('#ffffff');\n}\n\nfunction monthlyCalendar(m, wsd, ret) {\n  var m = m || new Date().getMonth();\n  var wsd = wsd || 1;//defaults to Monday\n  var ret = ret || false;\n  const td = new Date();\n  const [cy, cm, cd] = [td.getFullYear(), td.getMonth(), td.getDate()];\n  const dA = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];\n  const oA = [...Array.from(Array(7).keys(), idx =\u003e dA[(idx + wsd) % 7])]\n  let dObj = {};\n  let midx = {};\n  let rObj = { cA: null, roff: null, coff: null };\n  oA.forEach(function (e, i) { dObj[e] = i; });\n  const mA = [...Array.from(new Array(12).keys(), x =\u003e Utilities.formatDate(new Date(2021, x, 15), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), \"MMM\"))];\n  mA.forEach((e, i) =\u003e { midx[i] = i; })\n  let cA = [];\n  let bA = [];\n  let wA = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null];\n  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();\n  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();\n  sh.clear();\n  const year = new Date().getFullYear();\n  let i = midx[m % 12];\n  let month = new Date(year, i, 1).getMonth();\n  let dates = new Date(year, i + 1, 0).getDate();\n  cA.push([mA[month], dates, '', '', '', '', '']);\n  bA.push(['#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff']);\n  cA.push(oA)\n  //bA.push(['#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00']);\n  let d = [];\n  let ddd = [];\n  for (let j = 0; j \u003c dates; j++) {\n    let day = new Date(year, i, j + 1).getDay();\n    let date = new Date(year, i, j + 1).getDate();\n    if (day \u003c wA.length) {\n      wA[dObj[dA[day]]] = date;\n    }\n    if (cy == year && cm == month && cd == date) {\n      rObj.roff = cA.length;\n      rObj.coff = dObj[dA[day]];\n    }\n    if (dA[day] == oA[wA.length - 1] || date == dates) {\n      cA.push(wA);\n      //bA.push(['#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff']);\n      wA = ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''];\n    }\n  }\n  if (!ret) {\n    rObj.cA = cA;\n    sh.getRange(1, 1, rObj.cA.length, rObj.cA[0].length).setValues(cA);\n    if (rObj.roff && rObj.coff) {\n      sh.getRange(1, 1).offset(rObj.roff, rObj.coff).setFontWeight('bold').setFontColor('red');\n    }\n  } else {\n    rObj.cA = cA;\n    return rObj;\n  }\n}\n\nfunction monthlyCalendarWithEvents(obj) {\n  var m = obj.m || new Date().getMonth();\n  var wsd = obj.wsd || 1;//defaults to Monday\n  const calids = obj.calids || CalendarApp.getAllOwnedCalendars().map(c =\u003e c.getId());\n  const cals = calids.map(id =\u003e CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id));\n  const td = new Date();\n  const [cy, cm, cd] = [td.getFullYear(), td.getMonth(), td.getDate()];\n  const dA = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];\n  const oA = [...Array.from(Array(7).keys(), idx =\u003e dA[(idx + wsd) % 7])]\n  let dObj = {};\n  let midx = {};\n  let rObj = { cA: null, roff: null, coff: null };\n  oA.forEach(function (e, i) { dObj[e] = i; });\n  const mA = [...Array.from(new Array(12).keys(), x =\u003e Utilities.formatDate(new Date(2021, x, 15), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), \"MMM\"))];\n  mA.forEach((e, i) =\u003e { midx[i] = i; })\n  let cA = [];\n  let bA = [];\n  let wA = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null];\n  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();\n  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();\n  sh.clear();\n  const rtvnull = sh.getRange(\"A1\").getRichTextValue();\n  const year = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), m, 1).getFullYear();\n  let i = midx[m % 12];\n  let month = new Date(year, i, 1).getMonth();\n  let ldom = new Date(year, i + 1, 0).getDate();\n  var events = { pA: [] };\n  cals.forEach(c =\u003e {\n    let evs = c.getEvents(new Date(year, month, 1), new Date(year, month, ldom, 23, 59, 59));\n    evs.forEach(ev =\u003e {\n      let st = ev.getStartTime();\n      let dd = st.getDate();\n      let hh = st.getHours();\n      let mm = st.getMinutes();\n      let sts = `${hh}:${mm}`;\n      if (!events.hasOwnProperty(dd)) {\n        events[dd] = [];\n        events[dd].push(`${ev.getTitle()} - ${sts}`);\n        events.pA.push(dd);\n      } else {\n        events[dd].push(`${ev.getTitle()} - ${sts}`);\n      }\n    });\n  });\n  cA.push([mA[month], ldom, '', '', '', '', '']);\n  bA.push(['#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff']);\n  cA.push(oA)\n  //bA.push(['#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00', '#ffff00']);\n  let d = [];\n  let ddd = [];\n  for (let j = 0; j \u003c ldom; j++) {\n    let day = new Date(year, i, j + 1).getDay();\n    let date = new Date(year, i, j + 1).getDate();\n    if (day \u003c wA.length) {\n      if (events.hasOwnProperty(date)) {\n        wA[dObj[dA[day]]] = events[date].join('\\n') + '\\n' + date;\n      } else {\n        wA[dObj[dA[day]]] = date;\n      }\n    }\n    if (cy == year && cm == month && cd == date) {\n      rObj.roff = cA.length;\n      rObj.coff = dObj[dA[day]];\n    }\n    if (dA[day] == oA[wA.length - 1] || date == ldom) {\n      cA.push(wA);\n      //bA.push(['#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff']);\n      wA = ['', '', '', '', '', '', ''];\n    }\n  }\n  const dtnotcur = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).setForegroundColor('black').build();\n  const dtcur = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).setForegroundColor('red').build();\n  const evsty = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setFontSize(8).setForegroundColor('black').build();\n  rObj.cA = cA;\n  rObj.crtA = cA.map((r, i) =\u003e {\n    let row = [];\n    r.map((c, j) =\u003e {\n      if (c == '' || c == null) {\n        row.push(rtvnull);\n        return;\n        //c = ' ';//heres the current solution\n      }\n      if (typeof c != 'string') {\n        c = c.toString();\n      }\n      let idx = c.lastIndexOf('\\n');\n      let rtv = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(c);\n      if (rObj.roff == i && rObj.coff == j) {\n        if (~idx) {\n          rtv.setTextStyle(idx + 1, c.length, dtcur);\n          rtv.setTextStyle(0, idx, evsty);\n          row.push(rtv.build());\n        } else {\n          rtv.setTextStyle(0, c.length, dtcur);\n          row.push(rtv.build());\n        }\n      } else {\n        if (~idx) {\n          rtv.setTextStyle(idx + 1, c.length, dtnotcur);\n          rtv.setTextStyle(0, idx, evsty);\n          row.push(rtv.build());\n        } else {\n          if (c.length \u003e 0) {\n            rtv.setTextStyle(0, c.length, dtnotcur);\n            row.push(rtv.build());\n          } else {\n            row.push(rtv.build());\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    });\n    return row;\n  });\n  return rObj;\n}\n\nfunction quarterlyCalendarWithEvents() {\n  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()\n  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();\n  sh.clear();\n  const dt = new Date();\n  let oA = [];\n  let ids = ['jimesteban@jimesteban.com', 'q289qp9augtnshkn70dkibcc54@group.calendar.google.com', 'jtblvkkdfs7h06np3eqcb8rb4k@group.calendar.google.com'];\n  oA.push(monthlyCalendarWithEvents({ m: new Date().getMonth() - 2, wsd: null, calids: ids }));\n  oA.push(monthlyCalendarWithEvents({ m: new Date().getMonth() - 1, wsd: null, calids: ids }));\n  oA.push(monthlyCalendarWithEvents({ m: new Date().getMonth(), wsd: null, calids: ids }));\n  oA.push(monthlyCalendarWithEvents({ m: new Date().getMonth() + 1, wsd: null, calids: ids }));\n  oA.push(monthlyCalendarWithEvents({ m: new Date().getMonth() + 2, wsd: null, calids: ids }));\n  oA.forEach((obj, i) =\u003e {\n    if (i == 0) {\n      sh.getRange(1, 1, obj.crtA.length, obj.crtA[0].length).setRichTextValues(obj.crtA);\n    } else {\n      let lr = sh.getLastRow();\n      sh.getRange(lr + 1, 1, 1, obj.crtA[0].length).setBackground('#c2bbc9');\n      let sr = lr + 2;\n      sh.getRange(sr, 1, obj.crtA.length, obj.crtA[0].length).setRichTextValues(obj.crtA);\n    }\n  });\n  SpreadsheetApp.flush();\n  sh.getDataRange().setWrap(true).setHorizontalAlignment('left');\n  sh.setColumnWidths(1, sh.getLastColumn(), 85);\n}\n\nfunction colToletters(num) {\n  let a = \" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\";\n  if (num \u003c 27) return a[num % a.length];\n  if (num \u003e 26) {\n    num--;\n    let letters = '';\n    while (num \u003e= 0) {\n      letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[num % 26] + letters\n      num = Math.floor(num / 26) - 1;\n    }\n    return letters;\n  }\n}\n\nfunction copyto() {\n  const dssid = \"1Trccc5IszA2cLpUHKr2_I826e216u6is7ZWbD8ecx2U\";\n  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()\n  const sssid = ss.getId();\n  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0')\n  const sshid = sh.getSheetId();\n  const options = { \"method\": \"post\", \"headers\": { \"Authorization\": \"Bearer \" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }, \"payload\": { \"destinationSpreadsheetId\": \"\" + dssid } };\n  const url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sssid}/sheets/${sshid}:copyTo`;\n  let r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);\n  let title = JSON.parse(r.getContentText()).title;\n  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dssid);\n  let s = dss.getSheetByName(sh.getName());\n  if (s) dss.deleteSheet(s);\n  dss.getSheetByName(title).setName(sh.getName());\n}\n\nfunction breakUpRangeList(ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(), sh = ss.getSheetByName(\"Sheet0\"), rgl) {\n  let b = [];\n  rgl.getRanges().forEach(rg =\u003e {\n    rg.getValues().forEach((r, i) =\u003e {\n      let row = rg.getRow() + i;\n      r.forEach((c, j) =\u003e {\n        let col = rg.getColumn() + j;\n        b.push(sh.getRange(row, col).getA1Notation())\n      })\n    })\n  })\n  b = [...new Set(b)];\n  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(b));\n  return sh.getRangeList(b);\n}\n\nfunction flattenRangeArray(rangeArray) {\n  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()\n  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();\n  let rgl = sh.getRangeList(rangeArray);\n  let b = [];\n  rgl.getRanges().forEach(rg =\u003e {\n    rg.getValues().forEach((r, i) =\u003e {\n      let row = rg.getRow() + i;\n      r.forEach((c, j) =\u003e {\n        let col = rg.getColumn() + j;\n        b.push(sh.getRange(row, col).getA1Notation())\n      })\n    })\n  })\n  b = [...new Set(b)];\n  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(b));\n  return b;\n}\n\n\n\n//Drive.Files.update({\"parents\": [{\"id\": folder.getId()}]}, file.getId());\n\nfunction createPDFFromDoc(fileid, folderid) {\n  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);\n  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileid);\n  const blob = file.getAs('application/pdf').setName(file.getName());\n  const pdffile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);\n  Drive.Files.update({ \"parents\": [{ \"id\": folder.getId() }] }, pdffile.getId());\n}\n\nfunction makeCopy() {\n  var folderid = gobj.globals.folder1id;\n  var fileid = \"1lITNKyzlyLOWTla9c27x76GRAlAegF68\";\n  var folder = Drive.Files.get(folderid, { \"supportsAllDrives\": true });\n  var newFile = { \"fileId\": fileid, \"parents\": [folder] };\n  var args = { \"resource\": { \"parents\": [folder], \"title\": \"new Title\" }, \"supportsAllDrives\": true };\n  Drive.Files.copy(newFile, fileid, args);\n}\n\nfunction addingcharttoemaildraft() {\n  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();\n  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(\"Sheet0\");\n  const c = sh.getCharts()[0];\n  const img = c.getAs(\"image/png\").setName(\"myimage\");\n  const f = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.testfolderid).createFile(img);\n  let htmltemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah2');\n  htmltemp.filename = \"myimage\";\n  let imgObj = { img0: f.getBlob() };\n  let html = htmltemp.evaluate().getContent();\n  GmailApp.createDraft(gobj.globals.emailpub, \"Test File\", '', { htmlBody: html, inlineImages: imgObj });\n}\n\nfunction openUrl() {\n  let html = '\u003ch1\u003eDummy Dialog\u003c/h1\u003e\u003cscript\u003ewindow.onload = function(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(url){window.open(url,\"_blank\");google.script.host.close();}).getMyUrl();}\u003c/script\u003e';\n  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), \"Dummy Dialog\");\n}\n\n"
```

This one is fairly large.  I've been using the code for a while but recently I noticed some of the functions were missing so I began to search for a better solution.

I can get an array of objects from the functionSet of the same return from the API so I can loop through the functionSet and recover the exact function names but this one function named `breakUpRangeList` is giving me problems that I'm having trouble resolving.

This version only contains the function before and the function after:

```
"function copyto() {\n  const dssid = \"1Trccc5IszA2cLpUHKr2_I826e216u6is7ZWbD8ecx2U\";\n  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()\n  const sssid = ss.getId();\n  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0')\n  const sshid = sh.getSheetId();\n  const options = { \"method\": \"post\", \"headers\": { \"Authorization\": \"Bearer \" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }, \"payload\": { \"destinationSpreadsheetId\": \"\" + dssid } };\n  const url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sssid}/sheets/${sshid}:copyTo`;\n  let r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);\n  let title = JSON.parse(r.getContentText()).title;\n  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dssid);\n  let s = dss.getSheetByName(sh.getName());\n  if (s) dss.deleteSheet(s);\n  dss.getSheetByName(title).setName(sh.getName());\n}\n\nfunction breakUpRangeList(ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(), sh = ss.getSheetByName(\"Sheet0\"), rgl) {\n  let b = [];\n  rgl.getRanges().forEach(rg =\u003e {\n    rg.getValues().forEach((r, i) =\u003e {\n      let row = rg.getRow() + i;\n      r.forEach((c, j) =\u003e {\n        let col = rg.getColumn() + j;\n        b.push(sh.getRange(row, col).getA1Notation())\n      })\n    })\n  })\n  b = [...new Set(b)];\n  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(b));\n  return sh.getRangeList(b);\n}\n\nfunction flattenRangeArray(rangeArray) {\n  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()\n  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();\n  let rgl = sh.getRangeList(rangeArray);\n  let b = [];\n  rgl.getRanges().forEach(rg =\u003e {\n    rg.getValues().forEach((r, i) =\u003e {\n      let row = rg.getRow() + i;\n      r.forEach((c, j) =\u003e {\n        let col = rg.getColumn() + j;\n        b.push(sh.getRange(row, col).getA1Notation())\n      })\n    })\n  })\n  b = [...new Set(b)];\n  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(b));\n  return b;\n}\n\n\n\n//Drive.Files.update({\"parents\": [{\"id\": folder.getId()}]}, file.getId());\n\n"
```

The following function is the function I use to load a spreadsheet that makes it easier to find functions I want but I've noticed that some are  missing and that's what I'd like to fix.

I forgot to mention that the above examples are JSON strings so after messing around a bit more I finally found that this works:

```
function\s+breakUpRangeList(?!'\n}\n\n')[^]*?\\n}\\n\\n
```

GS:

```
function getAllProjectFunctions() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("ProjectFunctions");
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(gobj.globals.SOFJSONId);
  var jOb = JSON.parse(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  let files = jOb.files;
  if (files && files.length > 0) {
    var cOb = files.reduce((a, f, i) => {
      //Logger.log(f.name);
      a.table.push([f.name, f.type, "", ""]);
      if (f.type == "SERVER_JS" && f.source != null) {
        //a.source = JSON.stringify(f.source);//The is where I stringified the file source code
        a.source = f.source;
        //Logger.log('a.source: %s',a.source);
      }
      if (f.functionSet && f.functionSet.values) {
        f.functionSet.values.forEach(obj => {
          //let re = new RegExp(`function\\s+${obj.name}\\([^)]*\\)\\s*\\{.*?\\\\n\\}\\\\n`, "g");
          //let re = new RegExp(`function.*?${obj.name}.*?\\(.*\\).*\\{(.|\\n)*?\\n\\}`, "g");
```

This is the line I'm working on:

```
          let re = new RegExp(`function\\s+${obj.name}\\([^)]*\\)[ \r\n]*\\{(.|\\n)*?\\n\\}`, "g");//This is the regex that I wish to replace


          if (a.source.match(re)) {
            let src = a.source.match(re)[0];//once I began to stringy from above then this start functioning
            a.table.push([f.name, f.type, obj.name, src])
          }
        });
      }
      if((f.type == "HTML" || f.type == "JSON")&& f.source != null) {
        a.table.push([f.name,f.type,f.name,f.source])
      }
      return a;
    }, { source: "", table: [["File Name", "File Type", "Function Name", "Source"]] });
  }
  if (cOb.table && cOb.table.length > 0) {
    sh.clearContents();
    sh.getRange(1, 1, cOb.table.length, cOb.table[0].length).setValues(cOb.table);
  }
}
```

This is the line I wish to replace:

```
let re = new RegExp(`function\\s+${obj.name}\\([^)]*\\)[ \r\n]*\\{(.|\\n)*?\\n\\}`, "g");
```

This is the regex I've been working on:

```
function\s+breakUpRangeList(?!\n\}\n\n)[^]*\n\}\n\n
```

I have not been able to get either the negative look behind nor the negative look ahead to operate in this application.  So I haven't gotten to the point of converting it to be used in a RegExp.

> So the question I'm trying to ask is how to get everything from the end of the function name to the end of the declaration which ends with `\n\}\n\n`

This is what the function looks like in the project source file:

```
function breakUpRangeList(ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(), sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0"), rgl) {
  let b = [];
  rgl.getRanges().forEach(rg => {
    rg.getValues().forEach((r, i) => {
      let row = rg.getRow() + i;
      r.forEach((c, j) => {
        let col = rg.getColumn() + j;
        b.push(sh.getRange(row, col).getA1Notation())
      })
    })
  })
  b = [...new Set(b)];
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(b));
  return sh.getRangeList(b);
}
```

The final code:

```
function getAllProjectFunctions() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("ProjectFunctions");
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(gobj.globals.SOFJSONId);
  var jOb = JSON.parse(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  let files = jOb.files;
  if (files && files.length > 0) {
    var cOb = files.reduce((a, f, i) => {
      //Logger.log(f.name);
      //a.table.push([f.name, f.type, "", ""]);//causing duplicate entrees
      if (f.type == "SERVER_JS" && f.source != null) {
        //a.source = JSON.stringify(f.source);//The is where I stringified the file source code
        a.source = f.source;
        //Logger.log('a.source: %s',a.source);
      }
      if (f.functionSet && f.functionSet.values) {
        f.functionSet.values.forEach(obj => {
          let re = new RegExp(`function\\s+${obj.name}\\((?!\\n\}\\n)[\\s\\S]*?\\n\\}\\n`,"gm");
          //function\s+cleanGlobals\((?!\n}\n)[\s\S]*?\n}\n
          if (a.source.match(re)) {
            let src = a.source.match(re)[0];//once I began to stringy from above then this start functioning
            a.table.push([f.name, f.type, obj.name, src])
          }
        });
      }
      if((f.type == "HTML" || f.type == "JSON")&& f.source != null) {
        a.table.push([f.name,f.type,f.name,f.source])
      }
      return a;
    }, { source: "", table: [["File Name", "File Type", "Function Name", "Source"]] });
  }
  if (cOb.table && cOb.table.length > 0) {
    sh.clearContents();
    sh.getRange(1, 1, cOb.table.length, cOb.table[0].length).setValues(cOb.table);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine: https://regex101.com/r/moxi76/1

Comment: The negative lookahead looks weird. Provided that the code is valid, it will always match: there can be no `}` right after a function name. Perhaps you meant to write `(?:(?!\n\}\n\n)[^]*)`?

Comment: @InSync I'm assuming that I can't match everything until I reach this pattern of characters `\n\}\n\n`

Comment: @CinCout I guess I don't know how to use Regex101 because I'm still having difficulties at https://regex101.com/r/rAZjWx/1 and I don't see the difference between yours and mine.

Comment: I think the problem is that I did not say that the API returns JSON so \n in JSON is actually two characters.

Comment: @InSync thanks for the non capturing group idea it wasn't required but I added just to see and it doesn't seem to hurt anything.  It's so easy to forget this stuff.

Comment: @Cooper Oops, I made a typo. It should have been `(?:(?!\n\}\n\n)[^])*` (quantifier apply to the whole group). This is called a *[tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30900794)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this expression:

`function\s+breakUpRangeList(?!\\n\}\\n\\n)[\s\S]*?\\n\}\\n\\n`

Things to note:

1. `[^]` works in Javascript but not in the PCRE flavor as you'd expect, so use `[\s\S]` instead.
2. In order to match "\n" literally, you need to escape the '\' using another `\`.
3. The pattern needs to be made *lazy*, hence the use of `*?`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gkgBOx/3)

Comment: Thanks I just figure that out but I really appreciate your explanation as well.  I tested in in JavaScript also. Thanks again.

Comment: I think what you were missing was that the backslash in '\n' needs to be escaped

Comment: '[\s\S]` it took me a moment to realize the small and caps but with regex101 it's easy to see how that would work.